# C# Unable to serialize Class<T>

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am unable to serialize the following class...

```
[Serializable]
public class ClassA <T>
{
    public T Name;
}
```

when I attempt to serialize this class as an example...

```
[Serializable]
public class ClassB
{
    public int num;
    public ClassA<MyEnum> classA;
}
```

The json file outputted will contain `ClassB` with the `num` variable but will not include `classA`

Is it possible to serialize `Class A <T>` ?

To note, I am using UnityEngine.JsonUtility

Comment: I think JsonUtility doesn't support generic types, I seem to remember having read that. Can you try making a copy of ClassA that isn't generic and just see if that single change makes it work?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/214300/serializable-class-using-generics.html

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thank you for your help. Your answer solved my issue. I hope Unity, update the JsonUtility in the future but I will use the solution provided.

Comment: @Iggy Thank you for your help. Your answers solved my issue. I hope Unity, update the JsonUtility in the future but I will use the solution provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, afaik you can't directly serialize genrics but rather have to inherit from the generic class in order to make it work:

```
public class ClassA <T>
{
    public T Name;
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializeableClassA : ClassA<MyEnum> { }

[Serializable]
public class ClassB
{
    public int num;
    public SerializeableClassA classA;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer solved my issue. I hope Unity, update the JsonUtility in the future but I will use the solution provided.

Comment: @JakeMatthews The Unity Forums answer is from 2012 and suggests this, so don't get your hopes up

Comment: Yeah I don't think this will ever change ... 1. there is this simple fix so why should they  .. 2. It is related to serialization in general and I don't think you can serialize generic fields in general so it might be impossible to get the behaviour you expect into the JsonUtility